# Add empty item to list

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have the following code:

```
List.from((currentState as ItemsLoaded).items)..add();
```

I want to add an empty item and then assign a unique uuid in the class Item. How can I do this? Now it says that I need an argument for add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an empty Item, make sure your fields in the class are not required and then just

`List.from((currentState as ItemsLoaded).items)..add(Item());`.

or

`List.from((currentState as ItemsLoaded).items)..add(Item(id: yourUUID));`